# Can I store child game object's local axis and get it transformed to world axis at runtime?

Tags: unity-game-engine, axis, quaternions, euler-angles

I have a parent game object A, who has a child B, currently the use of B is just to get its world up axis (`child.up`) and world position (`child.position`) at runtime, apart from this they are of no use, so I decided to eliminate them by storing their local position and local rotation, at runtime I am parsing its local position to world like `parent.TransformPoint(childLocalPos)` but I am unable to find how to convert its local rotation to world axis, besides may be I am wrong that's not possible, please correct me.

Comment: Did you try `transform.TransformVector(childLocal.up)`?

Comment: lemme try...........

Comment: it works like charm !!! thanks @heejae